# accordion height and scrolling in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, height, accordion

I've got a 'card' layout, and one of the items is an 'accordion' type layout with a large number of items. The problem is that the content on some of the items cannot be seen because the accordion titles are placed above the content.

Setting `autoScroll:true` doesn't work because apparently the height of the layout is sensed by the sum of the titles heights (not the current elements heights).

```
var accordion= {

    id:'items-info',
    title: 'Items Info',
    layout:'accordion',
    bodyBorder: false,  
    bodyStyle: 'background-color:#DFE8F6;display:block;',  
    autoScroll:true,
    items: [{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    },{
        title: 'Title',
        html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
    }]

};
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine if you give the item panels a `fit` layout:

```
{
    title: 'Title',
    layout: 'fit',
    html: '<p>Item</p><p>This content just get lost</p>'
}
```

If not, your `bodyStyle` config may be overriding some style property that handles the problem.

Comment: tried this a while ago and didn't work, and now tried again without `bodyStyle` and still isn't working, now im going to implement the item list with a grid and coding myself the mutual-exclussion opening and closing.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `activeOnTop: true`?

Comment: What do you mean? If you set it to true active page should come all the way to the top of accordion, and hence content will be visible. Is it not the case in your code?

Comment: One more thing. Is it ExtJs4 or 3?

Comment: ExtJS 4, but the problem is that i have to deal with a LOT of items and the height of the panel is just not enough.... if i click and expand one of them there is no more room to push the other elements down. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you show how's your card is defined? One where accordion belong to?

Comment: the structure is as follows 'border'(top level layout)->'border' with west region->'fit' center region->'card' center region ->'accordion'

Comment: @Maluchi - I am having the same problem.  Were you able to fix this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427197/how-to-make-extjs-accordion-vertically-scrollable

Comment: Sadly, no :( I ended up implementing a different way to access the content.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
        layout:'accordion',
        defaults: {
            autoScroll:true
        },
        ...
});
```