# How to make extjs accordion vertically scrollable

Tags: extjs

[fiddle here.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5gv)

If there are many panels in the accordion they vertically just start bumping up against each other and can't be expanded.  I would like to make the total height of the accordion the height of the headers plus the height of one panel body (expanded).  And then the parent panel should just have a scrollbar to show that amount of height.  This way there is always an open accordion and you can scroll down to any header and instead open that one.

Is this not possible?

If I turn the layout of GroupListView to vbox intead of accordion I then get what I want but unfortunately when you expand/collapse the panels, the animations are all messed up (doesn't work like the accordion)

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 5.1.1, setting `fill: false` on the layout declaration seems to produce the desired result.